# Image to browser without saving

Tags: php, image, save

How can I put image from the memory to the browser, without saving.

For example:

```
 function getImage()
 {

   $imageFile = imagecreatefromjpeg('Map.jpg');
   $imageObject = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');
   imagealphablending($imageFile, true);    
   imagecopy(....);
   $ret = array($imageFile, $imageObject) ;  
   return $ret
 }
 <?php $ret = getImage(); ?>
 <img src = <?php $ret[0];? alt=''>
```

Is this possible, without saving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

Just try `imagejpeg($img);`

and put into `<img src=` path to the PHP script which render the image

See sample at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you would code your image to base64 and use it like that, it would work:

```
 <?php
    $img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'" />';
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAJEAAAAAAP///81Wv81WvyH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAKAAoAAAIUjIViq+x7QpunwXoZ lXFu/mjIUgAAOw==" alt="image" />
```

*I infered that you want to do this in one request.*

Comment: This will work with a single script file, if you can afford using second script, then @Jan Zyka and @Dobiatowski solutions are better.

Comment: This won't work in Internet Explorer < 8 and has severe size limits, and also destroys cachability. More often than not it's a bad idea

Comment: Yes indeed, I totally agree. But I guess, that's the only possible way, to do such a processing in one request, am I right ?

Comment: yup, that's correct. Doing this in one request is a bad idea for that reason

Answer (score 2):

You should have a script which sends proper headers and then it should be recognized as an image by the browser. Something like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// assuming you have image data in $imagedata
$length = strlen($imagedata);
header('Last-Modified: '.date('r'));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$length);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
print($imagedata);
ob_end_flush();
```

?>